# C# updating DataGridView query

Tags: c#

I dragged and dropped a datasource table, and as expected I got a box:

[image]

There's two more rows here, `"id"` and `"owner_id"`. I need `"owner_id"` to insert a specific value that is specified in a textbox. Where can I edit the query that is run when you add a row using `DataGridView`? owner_id in this table is foreign key to another tables primary key, the primary key is always found in a `textbox`, so I need the query to get that `textbox` value and set it as owner_id.

Comment: You can search for binding column content and textbox content, using param mode = twoWay.

Comment: @user2480500 You said "id" and "owner_id" as "rows", you mean probably columns? So, in that regard you want to add columns or rows?

Comment: It's possible to click in the gridview, write a name in the box and click enter to add the row. It gives me an error that owner_id column can't be null. I need to edit this query that is run, so it inserts into the table but sets owner_id = idTextBox.text.

Comment: Because you hide your owner_id so when you add a row the owner_id is NULL.

Comment: Is it possible to hide the owner_id, and add it with the idTextBox.text?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:

Based on your update you could probably use `RowsAdded` event but you need to initialize it first probably in your `Form1_Load`

```
  dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new   DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowsAdded);
```

And then when the user added a row you also add the value in the textbox to your dataGrid on the last Row. Let's say your "owner_id" is in the first column it would probably look like this:

```
    void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;

    }
```

Although honestly this would not update your bind table if you have just the DataGridView.

To see the effect you might temporarily show the hidden column after you add a row like:

```
    void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = true; 
        dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;

    }
```

Make sure by the way that your `DataGridView` property named `AllowUserToAddRows` is `True`

Comment: That's not what my code look like, I dont have any of that in the code, I dragged and dropped the table from "DataSources" into the form and I hide the owner_id column.